# RStudio Global Environment does not reflect in-place changes to data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

Background: I am using RStudio 1.1.456 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Kernel: 4.18.11-041811-generic, x86-64 cpu architecture (doubt this matters but just in case...).

Suppose I enter the following code to construct a simple data table:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(group = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"))

> DT
   group
1:     b
2:     b
3:     b
4:     a
5:     a
6:     c
```

In the "environment" tab, Rstudio displays an object DT with 6 observations of 1 variable.

Next suppose that I enter the following command (the specific choice of function, `.N`, doesn't change anything):

```
> DT[,numInGroup := .N,by = group]
```

RStudio's Global Environment panel continues to claim that DT has only 1 variable. However, entering e.g. `head(DT)` reveals that indeed the variable `numInGroup` was added and computed correctly:

```
> head(DT)
   group numInGroup
1:     b          3
2:     b          3
3:     b          3
4:     a          2
5:     a          2
6:     c          1
```

In addition, `View(DT)` also shows the variable. Finally, if I execute

```
> DT2 <- DT
```

the Global Environment tab displays DT2 as having two variables.

Finally, if I subsequently execute

```
> DT <- DT2
```

It still does not display the correct number of variables (maybe this is obvious - I am not used to R - but it's not what I expected to happen). It displays correctly if I do

```
> DT <- copy(DT2)
```

or if I do

```
> rm(DT)
> DT <- DT2
```

Evidently this is way above my pay grade. What is going on here? What am I not understanding about R / RStudio?

Comment: See the duplicate link but refreshing the environment pane should do it.

Comment: This helps but I'm still very confused by what's happening and I think it merits more explanation. E.g. if I type `DT <- data.table(group = c("b","b","b","a","a","c","d"))` it _does_ register the change. Whereas it does not work when I type `DT <- DT2`, where `DT2` is, as I explained above, the same as `DT` but with one additional column. So there's still something I don't understand.

Comment: Understood. I suspect this is a question for the RStudio or `data.table` folks. It might be worth reaching out to them if you want an answer. If they give you an answer, you could add it to this or the "duplicate" post.

Comment: RStudio does some low-level probing of R's memory structures to fill in its environment pane. data.table does some low-level mucking around of the same data structures to support in-place modification. Sometimes these don't play well together.